# Regarding a result about the degree of an element in a family of finite sets.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

We have a family $F = \{S_1, S_2... S_m\} $ of $m$ subsets of $\{1,2...n\} $, all with the same cardinality. We're given that $ \forall a,b \in \cup S_i $, number of subsets $S_i$ containing both $a$ and $b$ is the same, or, $|\{S_i : S_i \in F, a \in S_i, b \in S_i\}| = l $, for some fixed integer $l$.

We need to prove that $ \forall a,b \in \cup S_i $, number of sets containing $a$ is equal to the number of sets containing $b$. (or $degree(a) = degree(b)$.)

I attempted to prove it by contradiction, assuming otherwise, let $ \exists a,b \in \cup S_i $ s.t. $deg(a) \neq deg(b)$. Let the family of sets containing $a$ be given by $F_a$. We know that for another $c \in \cup S_i $, $|F_a| + |F_c| = |F_{a \cup c}| + |F_{a \cap c}| $. Writing this equation for $b$ as well and subtracting, we get

$$
|F_a| - |F_b| = |F_{a \cup c}| - |F_{b \cup c}|
$$

We need to prove the right side of the expression is zero, but I do not know how to proceed. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say number $1$ is in $d$ sets, WLOG we can assume in $S_1,S_2,...S_d$. Also uppose $|S_i|=k$ for each $i$ and each pair $\{x,y\}$ appear in $l$ sets among $S_1,...S_m$.

Then if we count the connections between set $\{2,3,...,n\}$ and sets $\{S_1,...S_d\}$ we have $$(n-1)l = d(k-1)\implies d = l\cdot{n-1\over k-1}$$
and we are done. We only have to think about the possibility $k=1$.

Clarly we can say the same for each vertex $\ne 1$, so $d$ is the same for all vertices.

Comment: Ugh, so simple! Thanks!